# Quit function only if Ajax request is finished

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I want to quit the `getUserID` function only if the `AJAX` request ist finished because the `UserID` is essential for everything else.

Unfortunately the function quits either way.

```
  $scope.getUserID = function (){
        $http.get('UserNormal-getUserId' ).success(function(data){
            $scope.userIDD = data['id'];
        });
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean you want to *"quit function"*? Just handle error cases properly.

Comment: Do you actually mean *wait for `http.get` to finish then quit `getUserID`* ? (Make asynchronous call synchronous, is that what you mean?)

Comment: use `resolve` with route feature: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Comment: This is because $.get is an asynchronous operation. This is very common in js. You should look into how to structure your code with callbacks or promises

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned use promise to check if AJAX request finished, the easiest way to do is is to use $resource (or RESTAngular) instead $http.